# Handling big data sets (neo4j, mongo db, hadoop)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, neo4j

I'm looking for best practices to handle data. So, that is what I got so far: 1.000.000 nodes of type "A". Every "A" node can be connected to 1-1000 nodes of type "B" and 1-10 nodes of type "C".

I've written a RESTful service (Java, Jersey) to import data into a neo4j graph. After the import of nodes "A" (only the nodes, with ids, no further data) i have notices that the neo4j db has grown to ~2.4GB.

Is it a good idea to store additional fields (name, description,...) in neo4j? Or should i set up a mongoDB/hadoop to use a key/value combination for data access?

Comment: In my opinion, 1 million nodes/few GB isn't enough to warrant going to Hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you delete a lot of nodes during the insert? Normally a node takes 9 bytes on disk, so your 1M nodes should just take 9M bytes. You have to enable id reuse to aggressively reclaim memory.

Could you please list the content of your data directory with the file sizes?

In general it is no issue to put your other fields in neo4j if they are not large blob fields.

How did you create the db?

Comment: hey! No i am not deleting nodes. I'm "just" inserting nodes with attributes "id", "name" and "code". The ID is an auto generated string (length = 32). The name is the counter when i am inserting the node (node 975.648 -> name = "name975648"). And the code is the same as name (code975648). I'll post content details of the data directory when i'm back at home ;)

Comment: what is the usecase for the name + code. Using just a long value w/o the prefix uses much less space. What version of Neo4j are you using? You might also look into (http://docs.neo4j.org/annotated/#short-strings and http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/configuration-caches.html to learn about disk usage)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've forgotten one fact. I am indexing the nodes. :D Just had a look at the file sizes. The neostore.propertystore.db is ~1.4 GB. And the index has quiet the same size. All together its resulting in ~2.8GB. I think, i need the index to locate the nodes?

Comment: And i'm using neo4j 1.5. In the real application the name and the code are different strings (length 30 - 150). It was just a test, because i've never worked with neo4j before. I planned to store documents in the db (node A). Each document can have fields (node B) and values. And every field can have its own versioning (node C). Is it a good idea to store this kind of data into neo4j or should i have a look at hadoop/HBase?

Comment: This is a reasonable model, so I would go with Neo4j. It is sensible to adjust your string_block_size to a suitable size for your common use-case (string-size).